# Avoid/skip deleting shape in visio

Tags: c#, vba, visio

I want skip deleting a shape if it overlaps with other shape.

so any idea in which event i should do this?

i tried to do that using,

QueryCancelSelectionDelete(ByVal Selection As IVSelection) but i can't detect which shape is being deleted

Comment: I am creating a add in using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Selection object is the collection of shapes that are going to be deleted when QueryCancelSelectionDelete is invoked. All of the shapes in the Selection object will be deleted unless you cancel the delete.

You can cancel the event, but then none of the selected shapes will be deleted.

Perhaps you could then programatically delete the other shapes in the selection that you didn't want to skip...

(Although if you try that, you'll have to be careful that you don't get called again in your event handler by your own delete action...)